# Clarification on load ordering of Meteor files

Tags: meteor

From the documentation, as well as all answers I could find, it would appear meteor files are loaded depth-first, and then alphabetically. I couldn't find any elaboration on whether files at the same depth are loaded alphabetically compared to all other files at that same depth, alphabetically within their folder but with priority given to alphabetical ordering of the parent folders, or some other variation.

Let's say we have the following files:

```
b/file0.js
b/d/file3.js
c/file2.js
c/a/file1.js
```

What is the order in which they will be loaded?

One interpretation of the documentation would be that the order will be `file1, file3, file0, file2` (the files at depth 2 are loaded first in alphabetical order, followed by the files at depth 1)

Another possibility would be `file3, file0, file1, file2` (the files in the b directory are loaded before the files in the c subdirectory). I'm guessing this isn't it, as the docs say the files in the deepest subdirectory are loaded first.

Finally, I could also see `file3, file1, file0, file2` happening (files in b are loaded before files in c if they are the same depth)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pesky loading order function is defined in [`/tools/packages.js`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/38bd2c98bfa9add29eebf0615b8c69a8c32cd5bd/tools/packages.js#L53-L93). Step by step, the following comparisons are made:

- .html files are loaded before non-html files,
- Files named `main.*` are loaded after all other files,
- Files containing `lib` anywhere in their path are loaded before those without `lib`,
- Files with more segments in path are loaded first,
- Files are loaded in alphabetical order.

The rules higher on the list have priority before lower ones, so for example non-main .html file is loaded before non-html, main file. In your case, the files

```
b/file0.js
b/d/file3.js
c/file2.js
c/a/file1.js
```

are first split into groups with the same number of path segments:

```
b/d/file3.js
c/a/file1.js
---
b/file0.js
c/file2.js
```

Then, in each of the group the whole paths are sorted alphabetically.

---

Let's walk through a more complicated example:

```
x/lib/0.js
a/index.html
a/main.js
a/f.js
b/lib/echo.html
b/lib/main.js
k_2.js
k.js
c.js
lib/widget.html
d/e.js
```

First, split the files into .html and non-html groups, html files placed first:

```
a/index.html
b/lib/echo.html
lib/widget.html
----------
x/lib/0.js
a/main.js
a/f.js
b/lib/main.js
k_2.js
k.js
c.js
d/e.js
```

Then, in both group, place `main.` files last:

```
a/index.html
b/lib/echo.html
lib/widget.html
----------
x/lib/0.js
a/f.js
k_2.js
k.js
c.js
d/e.js
-----
a/main.js
b/lib/main.js
```

Now, in each created subgroup divide files among those containing `lib` in their path, and those that don't:

```
b/lib/echo.html
lib/widget.html
-----
a/index.html
----------
x/lib/0.js
-----
a/f.js
k_2.js
k.js
c.js
d/e.js
----------
b/lib/main.js
-----
a/main.js
```

In the groups you've got now, create subgroups based on number of path segments.

```
b/lib/echo.html
-----
lib/widget.html
----------
a/index.html
----------
x/lib/0.js
----------
a/f.js
d/e.js
-----
k_2.js
k.js
c.js
----------
b/lib/main.js
----------
a/main.js
```

In these final groups, sort full paths alphabetically:

```
b/lib/echo.html
-----
lib/widget.html
----------
a/index.html
----------
x/lib/0.js
----------
a/f.js
d/e.js
-----
c.js
k.js
k_2.js
----------
b/lib/main.js
----------
a/main.js
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent example. Why do the docs not mention the prioritization of html files?

Comment: Perhaps it's not really important, as they don't contain your js code anyway and are compiled differently.

Answer (score 2):

They are loaded in the following order: `file3, file1, file0, file2`. So your last guess was right. This is true on both the client and the server.

I did a couple of other quick tests, and without digging into the code, I'd bet its sorted first by depth and then alphabetically by the full path.

To perform the test I just created a new project and added the file structure from your question. In each file I added a single `console.log` with the filename.